# Softrware Licensing / Registration component/framework?

Tags: licensing, registration

We use a home-grown Registration System for our software but I'd like to update it fixing a number of things including adding the ability to remotely activate/deactivate it (to facilitate Saas).

Feel free to suggest any good (in your opinion) VB6- compatible option. I can check out whether it meets our other criteria below.

Required Features:

- Activate multiple programs (Ok if it generates a separate code for each one)
- Works with VB6 and VB.net. A VB6-compatible DLL should be fine.
- Still supported (nice to have but not absolutely required
- Compatible with Windows 2000 through 7.

Nice-to-have features (but not required)
* Work without internet access
* Works through a firewall (this may be a tough one)

Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing or legal issues, not programming or software development.

Answer (score 1):

Check out ActiveX control: http://www.aztechsoft.com/timelock.htm

A little old school, but you should be able to wrap it in a .NET container using Interop.

Comment: Just to be clear, do you have personal experience with this?

Comment: I had worked with this for several years, I had written my own similar implementation of it as well.  I might have the source code somewhere if you're interested.

Comment: It looks like there's no "Phone Home" type over-the-internet way to activate and deactivate it, correct?

Comment: That's correct.  It's a disconnected activation.

Answer (score 0):

I found a list of Licensing systems. I'll go through each one to evaluate them:
http://software-licensing.qarchive.org/

Comment: Post back with your conclusions, this is an interesting topic. We use some hardware keys from SafeNet Sentinel (who also have products like the ones your asking about but I've never used them) http://www.safenet-inc.com/sentinel/